# Does NSUserDefaults save objects if the application becomes inactive?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

For example:

```
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
[user setObject:textField1.text forKey:@"receive_text1"];
[user setObject:textField2.text forKey:@"receive_text2"];
[user synchronize];
```

If I leave this app, just like from background to foreground, or relaunching the app

Could objects in NSUserDefaults still get the data that I set before?

Comment: I am sorry, I am the downvoter, but it was an accidental click and now I can't reverse it. Can someone please upvote to compensate?

Comment: If you click the down arrow again, it should remove your downvote. Its like a toggle button.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSUserDefault is persistent. So the data will be saved until you remove them or delete the app from the device.