# Why lost data when relaunch to APP?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsuserdefaults

I ask a question before [Link Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592550/does-nsuserdefaults-save-objects-if-the-application-becomes-inactive)
Someone answer the data won't lost

But I try to use NSUserDefault set my object,and close Application then open APP again.

The object in NSUserDefault  lost??I can't get them back.
How could I solve this problem??
THANKS~

Mini

Comment: Your previous answer was correct, NSUserDefaults is designed to persist small amounts of information. Why do you think your values are not being saved? How did you try to save them? How did you try to retrieve them later? If you do not show your code how can we determine what you have done incorrectly?

Comment: NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];   
[user setObject:textField1.text forKey:@"receive_text1"];
[user setObject:textField2.text forKey:@"receive_text2"];
[user synchronize];I think this is how she setObject to NSUserDefaults...according to she previous answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return value for call to NSUserDefaults -synchronize. It is possible that this is failing.

```
BOOL result = [user synchronize];
NSLog(@" result = %@", result ? @"YES" : @"NO");
```

If synchronize is not failing, then something odd is happening...

Comment: may be synchronize this way? [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]